# Heroku app crashes, logs say "No such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, nokogiri

I had a working app, added Nokogiri, to parse some xml, runs fine locally.

My Gemfile includes: `gem 'nokogiri'`

I ran `bundle install` and verified my Gemfile.lock includes `DEPENDENCIES` ... `nokogiri`

In my controller class I added (didnt thinkI had to but got an error locally if I didnt):

```
class MydealController < ApplicationController
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'nokogiri'
```

when I use my browser to get the url in MydealController that uses nokogiri `doc = Nokogiri::XML(getresult)` Heroku crashes.

`heroku logs` shows this error `No such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)`

Looking at what happens when I `git push heroku` I do not see nokogiri on the list of many many gems that get installed. Heroku says the push was fine, but nokogiri is not listed and I get the aforementioned error...

Comment: Did you not add Nokogiri to the `Gemfile` of your application?

Comment: second line of my text "My Gemfile includes: gem 'nokogiri'"

Comment: I saw a post (wiht no answers) on some blog suggesting might be some issue where I'm using windows locally, did bundle install locally, and then heroku barfs on the gem for some reason. seems implausible though.

Comment: the problem "went away" when I switched to a mac for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when using Windows `Gemfile.lock` will contain version of `nokogiri` gem specific for windows, **solution is to remove Gemfile.lock** and push to heroku.

More info on this subject [here](http://ganeshprasadsr.blogspot.com/2010/10/installing-nokogiri-for-rails-3-app-on.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your mission should you choose to accept it.

Ensure:

1. nokogiri is in Gemfile.lock
2. Gemfile.lock is committed to git
3. you push the commit that has nokogiri in Gemfile.lock to Heroku

Good luck! This message will self destruct in 10 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem -- you have to run `bundle install` to get it added to the `Gemfile.lock` which heroku looks at to find uninstalled dependencies.

Comment: yes I did that and verified it was in the gemfile.lock, as mentioned in the questions. seems to be an issue with my dev environment being windows. sigh.

Answer (score 0):

This might help to understand the reason:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps

Indeed removing Gemfile.lock might help. All other compiled gem will cause isseu. Best way is to ask Heroku's support.

Only found this article:
http://ganeshprasadsr.blogspot.com/2010/10/installing-nokogiri-for-rails-3-app-on.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `require 'nokogiri'` from controller.

It works for me.