# Nokogiri being removed on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, nokogiri

I have been having issues deploying to heroku with Nokogiri installed as a gem , I get the error no such file to Load 'Nokogiri' , I have searched around and it seems to be something to do with the gemfile.lock and some have suggested removing it but this doesn't work as heroku doesn't allow this so I don't know how to fix it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku app crashes, logs say "No such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964800/heroku-app-crashes-logs-say-no-such-file-to-load-nokogiri-loaderror)

Comment: I did read that but as mentioned I followed what as said but that no longer works , as heroku won't let you not commit a gemfile.lock